# How can I find the item in a list with the biggest number, and then add a number to a corresponding list?

Tags: python, list

The question may be a bit unclear, but I have two lists: one with scores, and one with wins.

```
scores = [140, 330, 260]
wins = [0, 0, 0]
```

In this example, I want to decide what the largest number is, which is the second item in the list. Then I want to add a win to the second item in the list (the corresponding one) to count the wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
scores = [140, 330, 260]
wins = [0, 0, 0]

index = scores.index(max(scores))
wins[index] = 1
print(wins)
# [0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enumerate` method to return a series of indexes and their values, and find the maximum value from there. This will also give you the index, which you can then apply to wins:

```
>>> scores = [140, 330, 260]
>>> wins = [0, 0, 0]
>>> wins[max(enumerate(scores), key  = lambda x : x[1])[0]] += 1
>>> wins
[0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to try this way:

```
winPosition = ""
biggest = ""

scores = [140, 330, 260]
wins = [0, 0, 0]

for highest in range(len(scores)):
    if biggest == "":
        biggest = scores[highest]
        winPosition = highest
    elif scores[highest] > biggest:
        biggest = scores[highest]
        winPosition = highest

wins[winPosition] += 1
```